# Azure Alert Processing Rules by tag

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I am trying to work with Azure Alert Suppressions to suppress servers for maintenance every month. The problem Im facing though is that they are getting unwieldy, for example we have 100 resource groups 50 in Group A and 50 in Group B that will have maintenance every third Tuesday for one group and every third Wednesday for the second group. Going in and manually changing these causes issues every month since Azure only allows 20 resource groups per alert processing rules there ends up being a lot of rules to manually change. Things are also added and removed from these rules, causing resource groups to get missed.

My question is, is there a way in Azure to implement Alert Processing rules via tag? Or a way to put in a non standard schedule, ex every third Tuesday? Or some other way to suppress all of these without going into every alert processing rule?

Currently running 50+ Alert processing rules in multiple subscriptions to manage this, looked into all settings and could not find a way to suppress via tag. Looked into Action groups and alert rules but also could not find a way to change all rules at once. So looking for anything that would be scalable to manage these rules as soon it will get out of control and be impossible to manage manually. I am considering creating a living bicep file to edit it which might just be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can utilize alert processing rules to suppress notifications during planned maintenance. Alert processing rules allow you to apply processing to alerts that have been fired.

- You can utilize alert processing rules to add or delete action groups from your fired alerts.
- You can also apply alert processing rules to multiple resource scopes, from a single resource to an entire subscription. You can also use them to apply multiple filters or have the rule run on a predefined schedule.

*Few approaches are given below:*

- Use Azure Policy to set up tag-based alert suppressions. You can disable alerts for resources with a specified tag by setting a policy that targets such resources.

  [image]
- Use `Azure Resource Graph` to query for resources with specified tags or others, and then utilize the query results to automate the development or update of alert processing rules. I ran below sample query for better understanding.

  [image]

Refer [MSDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-processing-rules.md) for more relevant information.

Comment: The azure policy looks like exactly what im looking for thank you! However, ive been poking around with it for a few days and I couldnt find an "enable monitoring" policy like you have listed, is that a custom initiative or am I just missing it somewhere? I understand the process that i need to get through but cant find the right initiative to put in place then filter.